# iOS 6.0 and HTML embedded images (RFC2397)

Tags: iphone, ios, image

Here is a HTML code of a simple page embedding an image (B64 coded) :

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS[...]UhEUgAAACAAAAAgI=">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

On an iPhone running iOS 5.0 this works and the embedded image shows up (at least in the Mail application, when I use this .html file as an attachment of my mail).

On an iPhone running iOS 6.0, the embedded image doesn't show up. It looks like Apple doesn't support RFC2397 anymore, but I didn't find any document telling so.

Do you have any info concerning this point ?

Thanks